# Visual Studio Community 2017 Workloads

Tags: c, visual-studio-community

Which workloads for Visual Studio Community do I download if I want to program C. Also, do you need to download GNU C compiler for Visual Studio Community if you want to compile C? If so, can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has its own compiler. I believe it included in the standard installation. Just follow the correct links. I have installed it couple of weeks ago but I do not remember now exact installation but it was more than straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to choose not via workloads, but via packages (or whatever they were called) and deselect everything except the Visual C++ package (which is often the first one in the list). I'm not even sure you need that, but it doesn't hurt as you may want to step up from C and tweak some Visual C++ too.

While they offer you lots of packages and stuff, to code in C you just need the compiler, so don't bother downloading the stuff you need and just make a lightweight install. You can always add the other components later if you need them.

About the GNU compiler, no you don't need that as Windows has it's own compiler (once VS is installed look for the "developer command prompt" in your programs to use it), however GCC (which is the compiler often used on GNU/Linux) is quite a standard and you may want to try that out too, just in case you're asked to code on Linux someday. The easiest way to use that is to install MinGW, [here's their guide for it](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/howto_install_the_mingw_gcc_compiler_suite).